# List bullet aligned to right

Tags: css, list, bulletedlist

**http://www.edsys.in/smart-card-solutions/** the list in the first block shows the first list bullet to the right side of the list compared to other.i have given

```
text-align:right;
```

to the list but did not work .

please help

Comment: What is the desired output, you want all bullet to the right ? Or the one that is actually to the right to go left ?

Comment: the one that is actually to the right to go left like the rest of the bullets

Comment: Alright, let me formulate the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that the star icon of class `icon_up` span into the block of your list for some reason, which cause the bullet to go the right.

Adding some `<br/>` before the `<ul>` will fix the issue.

**Edit :** Even if you accepted this answer, I did not found it was a good fix. An other solution less evil would consist of simply wrapping the `<ul>` into an inner `div`.

Comment: i added a float left to the ul

Comment: @MelvinGomez Please see my edit as I think it is a better solution, however feel free to choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Float: right;
```

I'm sure that is what you're asking for.

If you are looking to place the bullets on the other side, I think you may need to use an image.